# Sequential memory allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I'm planning a application that allocates a lot of variables in memory. In difference from another "regular" application, I want this memory be allocated in specific memory blocks of 4096 bytes. My allocated vars must be placed in memory sequentially. One after another, in order to fill the whole allocated memory.

For example, I'm allocating a region (4096 bytes) in memory and this region is ready for my further use. From now, each time that my application creates a new variable in memory (which is probably made in "regular" application with **malloc**), this variable will be placed in free space in my memory region.

This sequential memory allocation is similare to how an array allocation works. But, in my case, I need an array that will be able to contain many types of data (string, byte, int, ...).

One possible solution is to achieve this is by pointer arithmetics. I want to avoid this method, this may insert a lot of bugs in my application.

Maybe someone solved this problem before?

Thank you!

Comment: What about `std::vector `?

Comment: The obvious first question is: why? If you want an app which can read old ram values, you'll need to go a level deeper. If you want improved caching, just malloc at the size of the cache buffer and you're already going to be pretty much ok. There are several layers between an application and the physical ram, and each one knows how to do some level of optimisation. To bypass all of that isn't typically a great idea.

Comment: From your edit it sounds like you're trying to make a multi-type array. Using malloc a lot is *not* the correct way to do this. Malloc has a big overhead, especially for small numbers of bytes. I would suggest you simply define a union of all the data types you might use, and use a vector of those. Let the vector manage your memory (internally it will malloc a large block and use pointer arithmetic to reference items, and re-alloc as needed if your set grows). If you are storing your own objects, inheritance is the way to go (instead of unions).

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to do this is because I'm working with another device that executing my C code. So, my Host is doing the Init steps and pass the result into the device side for further processing. If I'm only could copy all the results from the Init step (main RAM) into the device ram (not the main RAM) in one step (copy the whole region - 4096 bytes) - this could be perfect in performance perspective.

Comment: C or c++? In c++ use allocators in c, your own version of malloc. As long as you don't have to handle the deletion of individual vsriables, this is rather simple.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` by no means guarantees that subsequent allocated blocks are on sequential memory address.  Even worse, most implementations use a small number of bytes before and/or after the allocated block for 'housekeeping'.  This means that, even if you're lucky that addresses are sequential, there will be small gaps in between the blocks.  So the actual allocated blocks are slightly bigger to make space for those 'housekeeping' bytes.

As you suggest, you'll need to write some code yourself and write a few functions with `malloc()`, `realloc()`, ...  You can hide all the logic in these functions and should not make your application code using these functions more complex compared to using `malloc()` if it did what you wanted.

Important questions: Why do you need to have these blocks adjacent to each other? What about freeing blocks?